# can not retrive data from db using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to get data from the db using the "get_where" phrase in codeigniter.

expected query to build is : `select * from tele_data where F_NAME="" and M_NAME="" and L_NAME="" and FACTORY="" and DEPT="" and COMPANY_NAME="" and DESIGNATION=""`

## my view

```
<div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span style="color:#ff4d4d">Factory Name :</span>
                <select name="fcode" id="fcode">
                        <option value="CMGM">Crystal Martin Ceylon - Malwatta</option>
                        <option value="CMW">Crystal Martin Ceylon - Wathupitiwala</option>
                        <option value="CMG">Crystal Martin Ceylon - Garments</option>
                        <option value="CME" selected>Crystal Martin Ceylon - Europe</option>
                        <option value="CMCG">Crystal Martin Central - Galagedara</option>
                        <option value="CMPK">Crystal Martin Ceylon - Kanthale</option>
                        <option value="CMCD">Crystal Martin Central - Dambulla</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>First Name :</span>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" >
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Middle Name :</span>
                <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname">
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Last Name :</span>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Department :</span>
                <select name="department" id="department">
                    <option selected>Select One</option>
                    <option value="IT">Information Technology (IT)</option>
                    <option value="HR">Human Resources & Administration</option>
                    <option value="IE">Work Study</option>
                    <option value="QA">Quality Assurance & Control</option>
                    <option value="LEAN">Lean</option>
                    <option value="GENERAL">General</option>
                    <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Company Name :</span>
                <input type="text" name="compname" id="compname">
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Designation :</span>
                <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation">
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit">Search Now</button>
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

I've given factory name="CMG" & Department="IT" as inputs to the form.others are blank.

## my controller

```
public function search_results()
{
        $sdata = [
        
                'FACTORY'=>$this->input->post('fcode'),
                'F_NAME'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
                'M_NAME'=>$this->input->post('mname'),
                'L_NAME'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
                'DEPT'=>$this->input->post('department'),
                'COMPANY_NAME'=>$this->input->post('compname'),
                'DESIGNATION'=>$this->input->post('designation')
                
                ];
        $this->load->model('users');
        $y=$this->users->display_users($sdata);
        
        //var_dump($y);die;
            if($y==TRUE){

                $data["display_Data"]=$y;
                $this->load->view("results/find",$data);
            } else {
                
                redirect("/index/home");
            }
    
    }
```

the controller captures the inputs and successfully pass data to the model

## my model

```
function display_users($sdata){
        
        $query=$this->db->get_where('tele_data',$sdata);
        
        $result=$query->result_array();
        var_dump($result);die;
        
        if($query->result_array()==TRUE){
            
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $vals){
                    
                
                    echo $vals['SD'];
                    echo $vals['EXT'];
                    echo $vals['F_NAME'];
                    echo $vals['M_NAME'];
                    echo $vals['L_NAME'];
                    echo $vals['FACTORY'];
                    echo $vals['DEPT'];
                    echo $vals['COMPANY_NAME'];
                    echo $vals['DESIGNATION'];
                    
            }
            
             
        
        return $query->result_array();
        
        
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    
    }
```

but the var_dump command gives me an empty array as the result.what is the reason for this?I've attached a pic of db for your reference.However when I run the query separately in MySql it gives me the expected result.[see the db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxlki.jpg) please help me to sort this soon.

Answer (score 1):

**my controller**

Try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tele_data');
        $this->db->where($sdata);
$query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter the data array part like the one below

```
$sdata = [

            'FACTORY'=>isset($this->input->post('fcode'))?$this->input->post('fcode'):'',
            'F_NAME'=>isset($this->input->post('fname'))?$this->input->post('fname'):'',
            'M_NAME'=>isset($this->input->post('mname'))?$this->input->post('mname'):'',
            'L_NAME'=>isset($this->input->post('lname'))?$this->input->post('lname'):'',
            'DEPT'=>isset($this->input->post('department'))?$this->input->post('department'):'',
            'COMPANY_NAME'=>isset($this->input->post('compname'))?$this->input->post('compname'):'',
            'DESIGNATION'=>isset($this->input->post('designation'))?$this->input->post('designation'):''

            ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked using CI for a long time and as far as I'm concerned if you have `AND` in you query, you should not use `get_where()` and instead should use `where()`

Obs: I'm sorry but my reputation doesn't allow me to comment.

Answer (score -1):

var_dump($result);die; what it is this
   you have added die function to your model code

```
 function display_users($sdata){

            $query=$this->db->get_where('tele_data',$sdata);

            $result=$query->result_array();
           // var_dump($result);die;

            if($query->result_array()==TRUE){

                foreach ($query->result_array() as $vals){


                        echo $vals['SD'];
                        echo $vals['EXT'];
                        echo $vals['F_NAME'];
                        echo $vals['M_NAME'];
                        echo $vals['L_NAME'];
                        echo $vals['FACTORY'];
                        echo $vals['DEPT'];
                        echo $vals['COMPANY_NAME'];
                        echo $vals['DESIGNATION'];

                }



            return $query->result_array();


            } else {

                return FALSE;
            }

        }
```

Comment: HI, @Amit because the "$result=$query->result_array();" give me an empty array as the result.So there is no point the run the rest of the code until this is sorted out.

Comment: Read Question Carefully "but the var_dump command gives me an empty array as the result.what is the reason for this?" @Amit